# How do I navigate different pages while my data loads and keep the state?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, signalr, blazor

I keep seeing websites that have this feature..
Picture there is a list of items, each item represents a process that can be started

```
Firefox | A browser | Offline | Start
Calculator | A calculator | Offline | Start
Notepad | A notepad | Offline | Start
```

Where the first column represents the name, the second one a description and then the status and the last one is a button that can start the service.
Now when I click start, I want the "Offline" span to turn yellow and the text should change to "Starting".
That's easy in theory, you just change the properties and class of the html..

Here is where the issue arrives.
What if I start the service, it changes the text and color etc, and then while it's starting me as a user, I don't want to sit there and look at it and wait for it to change to "Started" and turned green, I want to browse the dashboard while it's starting.
Well if I do that, it completely loses context and when I get back to it, it's just going to say "Offline" again and it won't even update once it's done because the context is gone. I thought SignalR was a fix for this but I guess not, is this something that can be done using Blazor?

Index page

```
@page "/"

<ServerComponentList />
```

ServerComponentList

```
<h3>ServerComponentList</h3>

<ul>
    @foreach (var item in servers)
    {
        <ServerComponent ServerName="@item.Name" IP="@item.IP" isRunning="@item.IsRunning" />
    }
</ul>

<button @onclick="ChangeStatus">Start</button>

@code {
    List<ServerModel> servers = new List<ServerModel>
{
        new ServerModel {Name = "My Server1", IP="127.0.0.1", IsRunning = false},
        new ServerModel {Name = "My Server2", IP="127.0.0.1", IsRunning = false},
        new ServerModel {Name = "My Server3", IP="127.0.0.1", IsRunning = false},
    };

    async Task ChangeStatus()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //Simulates starting the process..
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);

            foreach (var item in servers)
            {
                item.IsRunning = true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

ServerComponent

```
    <div>
        <span>@ServerName</span>
        <span>@IP</span>
        <span class="@rowClass">@isRunning</span>
    </div>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public string ServerName { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string IP { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public bool isRunning { get; set; }

    string rowClass => isRunning ? "alert-success" : "alert-danger";

}
```

[image]